# Error running adb: No Android device found - expo-cli linux

Tags: android, linux, react-native, expo

I am trying to run a react-native scaffold for android application generated using expo-cli. I get an error about running an adb device. How do I fix this?

I have tried upgrading the version of expo-cli but the error persists. Then I tried setting an adroind path (even though I am not using any android emulators) but still nothing is working.

```
$ sudo expo start --android
[sudo] password for nompumelelo: 
Starting project at /home/nompumelelo/Desktop/new/Have-To
Expo DevTools is running at http://localhost:19002
Opening DevTools in the browser... (press shift-d to disable)
Starting Metro Bundler on port 19001.
Tunnel ready.
Couldn't start project on Android: Error running adb: No Android device found. 
Please connect a device and follow the instructions here to enable USB debugging:
https://developer.android.com/studio/run/device.html#developer-device-options.
If you are using Genymotion go to Settings -> ADB, select "Use custom Android
SDK tools", and point it at your Android SDK directory.
```

I expected the react-native android app to show on my real android device through an expo client app.